# Is this an align: "none" bug in Vega?

Tags: layout, padding, vega

This visualization uses `"align": "none"`, but it looks like `"align": "each"` should look, as far as I understand:

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamVAkAzGmTSgyAJzYMcxkBEzmA1mvRMANkij2QAXy8ylZcSQXCDQAbVBAhCcQTCRTMjhMAH14QyxpEGIghicAJnzfCKQo9Vj4xKSAdxoAE3oMrJcctABmAAY2wo1i6Jc4UhcktqScJBqamnEjGUbm1ABGXK7I3v64QeHUsnSZSxqkTGiyhOStrAACAFpz3IAqPoGhkbGJqe8pIpL0B-Wn6rqYBk9gcjnETlVavQrjd7msNs9xpMjMseuofoN5hCAUCcPtDup5gQWudbucABTov6QmDQu6U4ajRFTACU70+q0emLOmBxeOihOJpIpcKe3NpsMeDJeSNZXgAujJ-vVUKB-IEXGiRcMlYDfBg4GkeSqbIZ1ZrJSkDdseXrGa8jMa1UFzb8pUzkTI3ABPCxG0BBU3qTTibQgJgWcQ1ELoPRNCCAmR2pHWJ0a75ahH294gXRNBDiaMtPXIUz2aPhGJenDRMwWKwyODiXQ1JygYH4406lOm53pzlY+p67ndgK9kCUrlW9K26VvY2zJydPx2NiOawL9SmOA1bO2BxwADyoygdC96+yi8oAh8Pg+ler6lrlgyjebrZA7ffXcdPbT45FmJdkOU5+iao5-hOlqGtmSZzqAG6oEuNgrmu84Xpu267ihh7Hqe55NJe143nemBVjW5jPg2TZsC21iftY36qr+LoYgOuoyMOP7gSxSSTtBM7uvhcxIXuq7vghIBbjueqiY4R7uHhaEEWgbRXjeXSkQ+6BPvWICvjR770Z21Ijmafa-IBJnAdBXFmf+-bDgJWZKcJMnYUJ0RSVh+7ySepEeSpanEaAmnkXWL7UbRxpGaAjFgXZkFARxIGmWOkGOYms4OvB6GIW5+4BegXn5WJvmKTlymIUFt4hWRj4Ubp+lRW2uIggxJm2WlAFsdmnFMdx5msRlICwdlmS5SJ7kuZ5mElXJuH+dNgVETV95hZRemRYZrUdrFHX9XZ8yULkAgShZPXWdaqUQd1w2jYVk0FUtRWzcuPkLWez2qStGl1dpDVsmt9XhfKXhAA)

Relevant documentation says "If set to `none`, a flow layout will be used, in which adjacent plots are simply placed one after the other. If set to `each`, elements will be aligned into a clean grid structure, but each row or column may be of variable size." https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/layout/

So it seems that instead of simply placing adjacent plots "one after the other", `"align": "none"` aligns elements into a clean grid structure, too.

I would expect `none` to result in a misaligned layout here, instead it literally looks the same as with `each`.

So what's the difference between `none` and `each`, then? Is this just a bug?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Rob The link is actually not just a link, as the entire example is encoded in the URL. So what you request is already done.
If you insist, I can copy it over in plaintext, too.